# How to automatically run "/bin/bash --login" automatically in the embeded terminal of gedit on ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, terminal, gedit

Background: I updated RVM to latest version and .rvmrc so that I can direct rVM to use the project specific gemset. But it now requires that the bash shell be a login shell. So I did that via  the Edit |preference of the Terminal of ubuntu. That works perfectly fine.

However, the embedded terminal of gedit is still not "run command as login shell". But I can remedy that problem by typing in "/bin/bash --login" onto the embedded terminal of gedit after it is launched.

That is an OK workaround, but I felt there got to be a way to automatically do this.

I tried to add the follow variations to the end of ~/.bashrc  file  and it worked sort of, but I had to ctrl-c to return to prompt mode. Another side effect, normal terminal now also requires me to hit ctrl-C to return to prompt mode.

```
/bin/bash -l -i
```

How can I tell ~/.bashrc  file  to execute that command and return to prompt mode without me hitting ctrl-C each time?  Or any other way to achieve this goal.

Thanks in advance.

p.s. I also posted on askubuntu

https://askubuntu.com/questions/226694/how-to-change-gedit-embedded-terminal-to-be-run-command-as-login-shell

Answer (score 5):

Add this to your bashrc script:

`[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"`

Worked for me.

(you still need:`PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting`

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

The terminal plugin is written in Python, so you could attempt to customize it. Note that if you edit the installed files directly, your changes will be overwritten when the package is updated.

Around line 90 of the "/usr/lib/gedit/plugins/terminal.py" file you will find a line that looks like the following:
`self._vte.fork_command_full(Vte.PtyFlags.DEFAULT, None, [Vte.get_user_shell()], None, GLib.SpawnFlags.SEARCH_PATH, None, None)`

Add the arguments to the shell inside the list:
`self._vte.fork_command_full(Vte.PtyFlags.DEFAULT, None, [Vte.get_user_shell(), "-l", "-i"], None, GLib.SpawnFlags.SEARCH_PATH, None, None)`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. However, my ubuntu 10.04 don't have same file you had.

Comment: it is in /usr/lib/gedit-2/plugins  and didn't find same code you had. Thanks for trying.

Comment: Guys, this way works too, but suggested by @damau works better!